# vue-chartjs Doughnut chart percentage display

Tags: vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to display the percentage of these storages as displayed in the below image.

I tried the following code, but the percentage is not showing.

**Code:**

```
fillDoughnutData(i) {
        this.doughnutChartData.chartData = {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: this.pieChart(i),
                    backgroundColor: ['#C4C4C4', '#F9BC0A']
                }
            ],
            labels: ['Volume used', 'Volume left'],
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return `${data.labels[tooltipItem.index]}: ${data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index]}%`;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

**Expected output:**

[image: expected image]

Any help please?

Comment: What exactly is this code outputting for you?  And how does it not meet your expectations?

Comment: It's already rendering the graph correctly, but i want it to display the percentage as in the attached image. The tooltip is supposed to do that, but for some reasons i can't decipher it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done without the labels inside the donut. Using Vue ChartKick & Chart JS
Just format your data to be of this form [['Blueberry', 40], ['Strawberry', 60]] and for the colors also you pass it as an array or your donut will get random color

```
<pie-chart :donut="true" :data="[['Blueberry', 40], ['Strawberry', 60]]"></pie-chart>
```

Then within the script tags

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import Chart from 'chart.js'

Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))

Chartkick.options = {
  colors: ['#A52A2A', '#D3D3D3']
}
```

[Click here to view the donut generated from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEBw1.png)

Comment: Hi Usman, thanks for the headup, but i'm not using these libraries in my project. i'm using vue-chartjs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show percentages in tooltips, it is possible.
It seems you put tooltips object inside chartdata object, whereas it should be inside options object. Like this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        // DO NOT PUT tooltips HERE
    },
    options: {
        // PUT tooltips HERE
    }
})
```